# SharePoint decodes ampersand character and breaks the link

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, url, powerapp

I am trying to make a link (in SharePoint) to a Power App I created, following this tutorial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/sharepoint-scenario-build-app

A problem is that the "EDIT LINKS" function (as described in step 7 in the linked page) automatically replaces all ampersands (the & character) with the escape character `&amp;` in the URL.
And this breaks the link to my Power App. I can't find a way to circumvent this. I am convinced someone else must have run into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very weird looks like a **BUG** but workaround edit/open below link:

```
https://.../_layouts/15/quiklnch.aspx
```

or

> 1. Go to Site settings
> 2. Click 'Quick Launch'
> 3. Change the desire link and hit 'ok'

Comment: Thank you l_b_t, you saved my day! Works perfectly! The quiklnch.aspx page is apparently where to go with this right now. I tried the Site Settings route at first but did not succeed!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the ampersands in the site url?

> You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a site name, in a
>   subsite name, or in a site or Active Directory group name:
>
> - Tilde (~)
> - Number sign (#)
> - Percent (%)
> - Ampersand (&)
> - Asterisk (*)
> - Braces ({ })
> - Backslash () (etc....)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names-fol

Comment: Yes, ampersands in the URL. Power Apps is generating it for you, and you are expected to just paste it in under EDIT LINKS. Links looks like this:

https://web.powerapps.com/webplayer/app?source=portal&screenColor=rgba(0%2c+176%2c+240%2c+1)&appId=...